# concatenate string to end of file in fortran

Tags: string, file, concatenation, fortran95

How to concatenate string to the end of file or to specific place in the file?
And what  the meaning of '*' in the folloing command:

```
write(10, *) 'blabla'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `*` specifies the format that the program is to use for writing out your variables; it specifies *list-directed output* which means that the compiler is free to choose a sensible representation of your variables when it writes them.  Your best approach to find out what your compiler decides is a sensible representation is to suck it and see; if you don't like what the compiler does, take charge by using *edit descriptors*.

The rest of your question makes little sense to me and I can't answer it.